# Do I have a forked remote set up properly on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

My company's repo does not allow pushes to it so the process is to fork it and push to your fork and make a PR.

I have my remotes set up as follows:

```
$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:heriettaLux/company-repo.git (fetch)  # my fork
origin git@github.com:heriettaLux/company-repo.git (push)   # my fork
upstream git@github.com:company-repo.git (fetch)
upstream git@github.com:company-repo.git (push)
```

Is there a better way to set this up?

I am on `master` now and when I do `git log`, I see:

```
$ git log
commit 21424... (HEAD -> master, upstream/master)
(Commit info)

commit 29128... (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
(Commit info)
```

I want to start a new feature branch but I can't tell if that means I am out of sync somehow?  I just want to make sure I have the latest of my company's `master` pulled in so I can create a new branch off of it.  I tried `git pull origin master` and `git pull upstream master` but both say it's up to date and now I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: The *setup* looks fine from what we can see here. This way of working is a bit tricky though, as there are now *three* Git repositories involved: one on your laptop (or other local computer), one on GitHub to which you can `git push`, and the corporate one on GitHub, to which you can only make a "pull request" from *your* GitHub repository. So now you have to maintain your laptop copy *and* your GItHub copy.

Comment: Your laptop (or whatever it is) is using commit `21424...` as the *current commit*. This is the same commit that `upstream` is calling `master`. Meanwhile, however, your GitHub repo is calling commit `29128...` `master`. That suggests—but since we can't see more, does not *say*, only suggests—that your GitHub copy needs a `git push` to get updated.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply fetch from the company repository before creating the new feature branch:

```
git fetch upstream
git switch -c newBranch upstream/master
```

That way, I can start working from the most updated upstream `master` branch.

Then I can fetch regularly from upstream, and rebase my feature branch on top of it, in order to make sure my work remain based of the latest from the company repository.